# merge two tables in OBIEE12C

Tags: weblogic12c, obiee

I am new to obiee and want to know how can we merge two tables in OBIEE12C with any of joins(inner,left,right,full).

Suppose I have two tables CATEGORY(category_id,category_name) and PRODUCTS(product_id,product_name),I want to merge PRODUCTS to CATEGORY table with any of the join(inner,left,right,full),so that the resulting CATEGORY table after merge will have columns(category_id,category_name,product_id,product_name).

How can I acheive this in OBIEE12C. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

First important thing: OBIEE (or OAS - the product which replaces OBIEE) works with *models*. Not queries.

You need to learn how to build repositories - i.e. metadata models.

Here's an example tutorial, but you can't just jump into it and think it will work the same way as writing a queryin SQL Dev.

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bi1221/rpd/rpd.html

Comment: Chris's answer is true, but if you want to make Analysis using sql query, you can try Create Analysis using Direct Database Request but you need to know the Connection Pool that is set in RPD

Comment: Yes, but that pretty much eliminates the core capabilities of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to merge tables in OBIEE using UNION, INTERSECT, MINUS operators. I've being using it for a while, and it works well.

You can check [here](https://it.cornell.edu/sites/default/files/OBIEE%2011/OBIEE11-8v3.pdf), in page 166 how to combine multiple analyses. It can be done using multiple tables or in the same table, depending on your needs. Just be careful to have all column types matching, otherwise it won't work.